# GIT-SVN in Xcode 5

Tags: git, svn, version-control, xcode5

I got a SVN server for all the source codes via https.

The address is similar to this:

```
https://192.168.1.123:1234/svn/external/trunk/
```

The current workflow for me to commit a Xcode project to SVN is as follow:

1. Create a new folder called "svn_repo"
2. In Terminal, issue command: `git svn init https://192.168.1.123:1234/svn/external/trunk/project1/`. Empty GIT repository is created
3. Issue `git svn fetch` to update from SVN server
4. Then I add the Xcode project files into the folder
5. Add modified files by: `git add .`. No output is shown, but when issuing `git status`, the changed files are tracked.
6. Then, commit the changes by `git commit -am "This is a duck"`
7. Last, push to SVN by `git svn dcommit` & `git svn rebase`

I think it's quite complicated. I know Xcode supports GIT, but how to support SVN also?